# Is Scratch's (sin of (n)) function incorrect, or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: function, math, trigonometry, mit-scratch, degrees

I found a [double pendulum ODEs simulation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/31pn44dlgq) on Desmos, credit to @AlexRLJones, and I am trying to recreate it entirely in Scratch.

While writing the code, I noticed that when I put sin(θ₁) with θ₁=50 on either Desmos or a calculator (on Google, my phone, a TI-84+ Silver Edition, you get the point), I get -0.262.

Though when I run it in Scratch, I get 0.766. I have seen things on Google that also say it is 0.766, so I know that it might be a valid answer.

If it is correct, is there any way that I can use math to convert Scratch's answer to the one that Desmos gives me?

Pictures for reference:

Desmos' Answer

[image]

Scratch's Answer

[image]

Google's Answer

[image]

TI-84+ SE Answer

[image]

I have tried to convert the two and tried to find the equation for the sin function, but I can't find a solution.

failed conversion attempt

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is about **degrees** and **radians**.

`Scratch` is giving in degrees:

If you google `sin(50 degrees)` you will get this:

[image]

If you google `sin(50 radians)` you will get this:

[image]

## What is The Relation between Degree and Radian?

A complete angle of a circle is 360 degrees of 2π radians.

2π radian = 360°

π radian = 180°

1 radian = (180/π)° = 57° 16′ (approx)

hope this clarifies...